# WPF Grid and TextBox not resizing

Tags: wpf, xaml, resize

I've got a simple UserControl. Toolbar plus two TextBoxes and a splitter in a Grid.  XAML design looks fine but at runtime the Grid and boxes don't expand to fill space.  The control is hosted on a TabControl TabItem, just like another canvas-based UserControl of mine that works fine. At runtime the text boxes are shown in design time size.

I replaced the Grid with two TextBoxes but they also fail to expand at runtime.  Even a single box fails.  StackPanels and other arrangements tried.  I'm missing something very basic.

```
    <DockPanel Name="TextViewPanel" LastChildFill="True" Height="100" >
        <ToolBarTray DockPanel.Dock="Top" IsLocked="True" Height="26" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <ToolBar Name="tbTextView" Height="26" Width="500" TabIndex="10" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
                 (Button defs)
            </ToolBar>
        </ToolBarTray>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBox Name="TextBox1" Grid.Column="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True" AcceptsTab="True" TextChanged="TextBox1_TextChanged" ></TextBox>
            <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                Background="LightGray" 
                ShowsPreview="True"
                Width="5">
            </GridSplitter> 
            <DockPanel Grid.Column="2" LastChildFill="true" >
                <TextBlock Text=" Notes:" DockPanel.Dock="Top" FontSize="11" Background="LightGray" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                <TextBox Name="TextBox2" DockPanel.Dock="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True" AcceptsTab="True"></TextBox>
            </DockPanel>
        </Grid>
    </DockPanel>
```

Comment: Can you also share where the control is going? The issue is probably in that tab control. For me, the two boxes stretch the width of the Window, but the Toolbar does not. I am assume that the toolbar is intentional, though, since the width is hard-coded there.

Comment: It does not reproduce. The TextBoxs expands/shrinks as the GridSplitter moves.

Comment: Part 1 of my learning -- setting text boxes to a pleasant working size at design time hard codes their runtime size.  Leaving their dimensions/alignments as Auto/Stretch allows them to resize to whatever text they contain.  This is an improvement but I need to have the boxes fill available space.